# Django models filter is slow on one item

Tags: django, performance, django-models, django-queryset

I have a project model that has a FK to a group model. Group has name and two other fields: (bool) is_private indicating if the group is private and FK to django.auth.models.Group to indicate the group membership that this project group is visible to.

There are 100 projects and they are happily fetched in less than 1 second:

```
def project_list(request):
    parameters = {field_name: value for field_name, value in request.GET.items() if value and field_name in project._meta.get_all_field_names()}
    all_projects = project.objects.select_related().filter(**parameters)
    return  all_projects
```

there is only one project with a private group and as soon as I add the privacy check, the fetch it taking more than 4 seconds to do:

```
def project_list(request):
    parameters = {field_name: value for field_name, value in request.GET.items() if value and field_name in project._meta.get_all_field_names()}
    all_projects = project.objects.select_related().filter(**parameters)
    for p in all_projects.filter(group__is_private = True):
        if not request.user.groups.filter(name = p.group.private_group.name).exists():
        all_projects = all_projects.exclude(id=p.id)
    return  all_projects
```

Is there a way to redo this to take less time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below you're fetching single `group` in every iteration, so you're making lot of database queries which slows things down:

```
all_projects = project.objects.select_related().filter(**parameters)
for p in all_projects.filter(group__is_private = True):
    if not request.user.groups.filter(name = p.group.private_group):
```

If you want to fetch projects without private group or with private group only if user is in that group, then use:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def project_list(request):
    parameters = {field_name: value for field_name, value in request.GET.items() if value and field_name in project._meta.get_all_field_names()}

    group_ids = request.user.groups.values_list('id', flat=True)
    all_projects = project.objects.select_related().filter(**parameters)
    all_projects = all_projects.filter(Q(group__is_private=False) | Q(group__is_private=True, group_id__in=group_ids))
    return  all_projects
```

Comment: not that I want to select only projects with private groups - I want to select all projects but if there are projects with private groups I want them to be on the list only if requesting user is a member of the project_group_(FK)_private_group

Comment: I Modified the code to reflect that. I used [Q query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to filter "(group not private) or (group private and user has that group)"

Comment: yeh, just in case someone else uses this solution - need to add "| group = None" and replace droup_id with private_group__id